# SQLDataSource not showing in design view ASP.net C#

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, sqldatasource

I am attempting to build a report in Visual Studio 2015 using ASP backed with C#. however, any time i try to add the SQLDataSource control it will add the ASP code but will not show the control in the design view.

I have tried repairing my install as well as re-downloading and running the installer again.

I have attempted to search google as well as the stack overflow list and have yet to find anything. can anyone offer suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this configuration in your Visual Studio, it worked for me.

> Many ASP.NET controls do not have a visual representation at run time. The control is always visible in Code view. If you do not see a representation of the control in Design view, on the View menu, point to Visual Aids and then click ASP.NET Non Visual Controls.

Hope it helps.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295347.aspx) is the source.